# How to matching variable in ts and the value of the Directive from the html?

Tags: angular, typescript

There is a Directive in which the following code matching results if and hides the content to the user with another role

```
import {
  Directive,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  TemplateRef,
  ViewContainerRef
} from '@angular/core';

import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { User, UserService, Profile, ProfilesService } from '../shared';

@Directive({ selector: '[userRoles]' })
export class UserRolesDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private userService: UserService,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private profilesService: ProfilesService
  ) {}

  profile: Profile;
  roles: string;
  currentUser: User;


  ngOnInit() {
            this.route.data.subscribe(
              (data: {profile: Profile}) => {
                this.profile = data.profile;
                this.userService.currentUser.subscribe(
                  (userData: User) => {
                    this.currentUser = userData;
                    console.log(this.currentUser.roles);
                    if (this.currentUser.roles == ) {
                        this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
                    } else {
                        this.viewContainer.clear();
                  }
                  }
                );
              }
            );
  }

  @Input() set userRoles(roles: string) {
    this.roles = roles;
  }

}
```

There is html code where I output the value of this Directive

```
<div class="col-sm-12" *userRoles="['Admin']">
        <div class="feed-toggle mt-3">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills outline-active">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link"
                 [ngClass]="{'active': listConfig.type === 'feed'}"
                 (click)="setListTo('feed')">
```

Guys help, how do I make matching of this.currentUser.roles and userRoles results
Indexof not working, or I'm doing something wrong.

```
!this.userRoles || this.userRoles.indexOf(this.currentUser.roles) != -1
```

PS: if I have multiple directives on the page, will the system work?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.currentUser.roles == this.role[0]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.